# Google Cloud Dataflow TextIO to BigQueryIO Job does not start

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I am getting the following console log and the process stops

```
com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner fromOptions
INFO: PipelineOptions.filesToStage was not specified. Defaulting to files from the classpath: will stage 69 files. Enable logging at DEBUG level to see which files will be staged.
```

My execution parameters are as follows

```
--project=xyz-123 --stagingLocation=gs://xxx/staging/ --output=yyy:zzz.aa --runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner
```

I have run pipelines without specifying staging file list but all of a sudden this happens.

Comment: Did you call p.run() in your main program?

Comment: was about to close the question. you are absolutely right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though all the logs are in red, there is nothing wrong with the log or the code. I had simply forgotten to run my pipeline.

Maybe a lint or marker error in Eclipse might help in avoiding this kind of scenario.

Solution:

`p.run();`

had to be added since, I accidentally deleted that line.